# CPU Usage shoots all of a sudden while using Ubuntu in Virtual box in MBP

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, virtualbox

I an using 2015 model of MacBook Pro running Mac OS X Yosemite. I have installed Oracle VirtualBox 4.3.26 which runs Ubuntu 14.04 operating system. I have also installed the guest edition to improve performance.

When I open a large text file and scroll a view. There is a significant amount of lag along with high CPU usage. Which heats up the laptop. Can someone please explain this or provide a suggestion to improve the performance of Virtual Box?

Comment: How do you know it is the CPU that shoots up? You could perhaps try to go to the Activity monitor and checking on that

Comment: Well, that's what i did it. I am not making it on my own

Comment: To increase RAM is a tutorial [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=49071) And for CPU [here](http://superuser.com/questions/823109/how-to-allocate-more-processor-power-to-my-ubuntu-based-virtualbox-system-in-w) Also try shutting down every app possible on your Mac and logging out of all except of one users